# url not recognizend in LocalBusiness schema.org

Tags: google-search-console, structured-data

I have tried to test my markup code in [Google Structured Data Test Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) but it returns me a error:

```
    <script type="application/ld+json">
  {
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "LocalBusiness",
    "name": "BlaBlaBla",
    "alternateName":"BlaBlaBla.ro",
    "url": "http://blablabla.ro",
    "logo":"http:\/\/blablabla.ro\/img\/logo.png",
    "sameAs": ["http:\/\/twitter.com\/BlaBlaBlaRO",
        "http:\/\/plus.google.com\/BlaBlaBlaRO",
        "http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/BlaBlaBlaRO"
    ],
  "openingHours": "Mo,Tu,We,Th,Fr 09:00-17:00",
    "contactPoint" : [
    { "@type" : "ContactPoint",
      "telephone" : "+40300000000",
      "contactType" : "customer service",
      "areaServed" : "RO"
    } ],

  "address": [{
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "addressLocality": "City Name",
    "addressRegion": "RO",
    "streetAddress": "Street Adress",
  "postalcode": "000000"
  }]

  }
    </script>
```

The error is:

> http://blablabla.ro (All values provided for http://www.example.com/ must have the same domain.)

What can i do to solve this issue? Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you remove "ContactPoint" - the error will disappear.

But, I would not be worried about this, as a lot of people writes about the bug in SDTT. All other validators show you have everything fine.